# Get notified when command+enter is typed on a NSTextField using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am building an application where I wish to do something when the user types `command+enter` inside of a `NSTextField`*.

What is the best way to get a callback when `command+enter` is typed inside a `NSTextField` using Swift?

*I am creating my NSTextField programmatically, not using IB, so I would prefer solutions that aren't explicitly IB-centric.

Comment: Implement `performKeyEquivalent` somewhere in the responder chain?

Comment: @Willeke I'm not sure what that means. Can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: I don't do Swift and can't give an answer. Search Apple's documentation for information about the responder chain and `performKeyEquivalent`. Search SO for snippets with `performKeyEquivalent`.